# Common Table Expressions to retrieve path

Tags: sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression

I'm trying to use a recursive query to find a path through a table structured like this:

**RelatedEntities**

```
FromKey TINYINT
ToKey TINYINT
...more....
```

I thought I could do something like this:

```
DECLARE @startKey UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, @endKey UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
SET @startKey = 0;
SET @endKey = 3;

;With findPath
AS
(
    SELECT FromKey, ToKey
    FROM RelatedEntities
    WHERE FromKey = @startKey

    UNION ALL

    SELECT FromKey, ToKey
    FROM RelatedEntities r
    JOIN findPath b
    ON r.FromKey = b.ToKey
    AND r.FromKey NOT IN (SELECT FromKey FROM b)
)
SELECT * FROM findPath;
```

This code fails because I cannot use a subquery within a CTE.  It also seems to be a rule that the recursive query can only contain one reference to the CTE.  (true?)  Maybe this is a job for a cursor, or procedural code, but I thought I would put it out here in case I'm missing a way to find a path through a table with a CTE?

The parameters are:

1. Start with a beginning and ending key
2. Base query uses the beginning key
3. Recursive query should stop when it contains the ending key, (have not been able to figure that one out) and should not repeat start keys.
4. A MAXRECURSION option could be used to stop after a certain number of iterations.

Thanks to all of you CTE gurus out there. Set me straight.

Changing this from UNIQUEIDENTIFIERS to TINYINT for readability.  The SQL constructs are the same.  Here's some code to test it.

```
CREATE TABLE RelatedEntities(FromKey TINYINT, ToKey TINYINT);

INSERT RelatedEntities(FromKey, ToKey)
VALUES
(1, 0),
(0, 1), 
(1, 7),
(7, 1),
(3, 4),
(4, 3)

;With FindPath 
AS
(
    SELECT FromKey, ToKey, 0 AS recursionLevel
    FROM RelatedEntities
    WHERE FromKey = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT r.FromKey, r.ToKey, recursionLevel = recursionLevel + 1
    FROM RelatedEntities r
    INNER JOIN FindPath b ON r.FromKey = b.ToKey
    WHERE b.ToKey <> 3 AND RecursionLevel < 10
)
SELECT * FROM FindPath
ORDER BY recursionLevel
```

Note that this returns from 1, to 0, then from 0, to 1, and repeats until I run out of recursion levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify your query like this:

```
DECLARE @startKey UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, @endKey UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
DECLARE @maxRecursion INT = 100
SET @startKey = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000';
SET @endKey = 'F7801327-C037-AA93-67D1-B7892F6093A7';

;With FindPath
AS
(
    SELECT FromKey, ToKey, 0 AS recursionLevel
    FROM RelatedEntities
    WHERE FromKey = @startKey

    UNION ALL

    SELECT r.FromKey, r.ToKey, recursionLevel = recursionLevel +1
    FROM RelatedEntities r
    INNER JOIN FindPath b ON r.FromKey = b.ToKey
    WHERE b.ToKey <> @endKey AND recursionLevel < @maxRecursion
)
SELECT * FROM FindPath;
```

The *anchor member* of the above `CTE`:

```
SELECT FromKey, ToKey, 0 AS recursionLevel
FROM RelatedEntities
WHERE FromKey = @startKey
```

will select the *starting record*, `T0`, of the (From, To) chain of records.

The recursive member of the `CTE`:

```
SELECT r.FromKey, r.ToKey, recursionLevel = recursionLevel +1
FROM RelatedEntities r
INNER JOIN FindPath b ON r.FromKey = b.ToKey
WHERE b.ToKey <> @endKey AND recursionLevel < @maxRecursion
```

will be executed with `T0`, `T1`, ... as an input and `T1`, `T2`, ... respectively as an output.

This process will continue adding records to the final result set until an empty set is returned from the recursive member, i.e. until a record with `ToKey=@endKey` has been added to the result set, *or* `@maxRecursion` level has been reached.

**EDIT:**

You can use the following query in order the effectively handle any circular paths:

```
;With FindPath 
AS
(
    SELECT FromKey, ToKey, 
           0 AS recursionLevel,
           CAST(FromKey AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS FromKeys
    FROM RelatedEntities
    WHERE FromKey = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT r.FromKey, r.ToKey, 
           recursionLevel = recursionLevel + 1,
           FromKeys = FromKeys + ',' + CAST(r.FromKey AS VARCHAR(MAX))
    FROM RelatedEntities r
    INNER JOIN FindPath b ON r.FromKey = b.ToKey
    WHERE (b.ToKey <> 3) 
          AND (RecursionLevel < 10) 
          AND PATINDEX('%,' + CAST(r.ToKey AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ',%', ',' + FromKeys + ',') = 0  
)
SELECT * FROM FindPath
ORDER BY recursionLevel
```

Calculated field `FromKeys`  is used to carry on `FromKey` on to the next recursion level. This way any keys from previous recursion levels are accumulated from level to level using *string concatenation*. `PATINDEX` is then used to check whether a circular path has been met.

[**SQL Fiddle Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1df03/1)

Comment: Thank you, but this does not prevent the query from repeating start keys.  IE, if if my startkey is @a and my endkey is @b, but @a refers to @c which in turn refers back to @a, I will never get to @b.  That's why I had the NOT IN clause in the recursive member, but TSQL does not allow it.  I'm thinking there's got to be something obvious that I'm overlooking in the JOIN clause which would allow this, but it escapes me so far.

Comment: @user3481891 Can you post some sample data demontrating the problem along with required output?

Comment: @user3481891 Please also note that recursive CTEs operate in the way I tried to describe above, i.e. each recursion is applied to just the resulting record of the previous recursion level and not to the union of all records produced during the previous recursion steps.

Comment: I think you nailed it.  I have no way of accessing the union of all previous records, so I need to solve this problem procedurally or resort to a cursor.  Is that your assessment?

Comment: I went ahead and posted code in response to your request.  Run it and you will see the issue I'm talking about.

Comment: @user3481891 You can have a look at the edit I made. I also think you should correct your sample data: they contain two separate starting points and there is not path to the final `ToKey` value.

Comment: The sample data is correct.  The real data has hundreds of different starting points, hundreds of thousands of rows and any particular pair of points may or may not have a connecting path.  The point of this exercise is to first determine whether that path exists, and second return it if it exists.

Comment: The PATINDEX definitely works.  I've marked it as such.